# Hilbert Space and dual

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hilbert Space and $\varphi \in X' \setminus \left\{0\right\}$. We write
$$C=\left\{x \in X: \varphi(x)=1\right\}$$
and
$$E=\left\{\lambda x: \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, x \in C\right\}.$$

Now I have to prove that, if $\varphi(x)=0$, then there exists a sequence $(x_h)$ in $E$, such that $$\lim_h x_h = x.$$ How can I find out this sequence? I thought that the statement is equivalent to the fact that $x$ is aderent to $E$, still I can't go ahead.

Thanks to those who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\varphi$ is not trivial, there exists $u$ with $\varphi(u)=1$, consider $u_n=x+u/n$ where $n$ is a strictly positive integer, you have $\varphi(nu_n)=\varphi(nx+u)=1$, this implies that $u_n\in E$, $lim_nu_n=x$.

Comment: Do you mean there exists $u$ with $\varphi(u) \neq 0$, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I mean that

Comment: Thanks then! You helped me to solve it